# Icons as selectable items in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a list of icons which look like this:
[image]

In my view I retrieve the icon and name from my angular controller.
This is the how the html for this looks like currently:

```
<label-content label="File Format" required="true">
                <span class="col-xs-6">
                    <span ng-repeat="item in formats">
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i ng-click="setReportFormat(item.name)" class={{item.icon}}  aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="col-xs-10" style="padding-left:18.45em">
                    <span ng-repeat="item in formats">
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;{{item.name | uppercase}}
                    </span>
                </span>
</label-content>
```

What I want to accomplish is to have the icons show in a manner like this: [image]

Basically when the icon is selected the others should be grayed out and the one which is selected should be highlighted.

Still new to CSS and angular so any pointers on how I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you could clean up as need be. but heres how I'd approach it.

```js
angular.module("foo",[])
.controller("foo_c",["$scope",function($scope){
    $scope.icon_list = [{'img_type' : 'PDF', 'item_selected' : false},
                        {'img_type' : 'XLSX', 'item_selected' : false},
                        {'img_type' : 'CSV', 'item_selected' : false}]
    
  }])
.directive("icon", function(){
    return {
      restrict:"E",
      template:"<div ng-click='setSelected()' ng-class='icon.item_selected ? \"selected\" : \"disabled\" ' ><img ng-src='icon.img_type'  /><span ng-bind='icon.img_type'></span> </div>",
      scope : {
        icon:'='
        },
      link : function(scope, e, a ){
         console.log("Setting up ", scope.icon); 
         scope.setSelected = function(){
           scope.icon.item_selected = ! scope.icon.item_selected;
         }
        }
    };
  
  });
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: blue; 
}
.disabled {
  opacity : .7;
}
icon {
  border: 1px black solid;
  padding: 5px;
  display :inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="foo" ng-controller="foo_c" >
  <div ng-bind="icon_list | json"></div>
  <p> File Types </p>
  <icon icon="icon" ng-repeat="icon in icon_list" ></icon>  
</div>
```

Comment: Used a version of this without the directive and added the class attributes in the span directive itself. Although this answer is more efficient I already had code set in my controller to handle the ngClass conditonals.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) on the `<span>` with the `ng-repeat` and feed the `ng-class` some variable that changes in the controller to dictate which icon is selected.  Maybe use `track by $index` and key off of that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best scenario for using label with input type checkbox. in HTML you can do something like `<input type="checkbox" id= "pdf"> <label for="pdf"> </label><input type="checkbox" id= "xls"> <label for="xls"> </label><input type="checkbox" id= "csv"> <label for="csv"> </label>`. Now hide the checkbox using `display: none;` and label will work as checkbox for you. give labels background same is those images.